# .dll files need different SDK

Tags: java, dll, sdk, java-native-interface

I have some java code that requires two .dll files. However one requires the 32 bit SDk while the other requires the 64 bit SDK. One .dll cannot be found when the other's SDK is used. Im using IntelliJ on windows 7. whats the solution?

Comment: You can't mix the "bit deepness" - you should have a x64 AND x32 bit version of both - that way, it won't matter which version of the JVM you're using

Comment: I have both SDK but I can only use one, ie select one from project structure. An error pops up irrespective of which i use saying the other .dll cant be found thats compatible

Answer (score 0):

I only solution that worked for me was to run the program as two different processes that communicate using UDP sockets